# Angular JS - Character counter across multiple text inputs

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Angular JS app I am building along with Angular-UI (bootstrap).

I have a set of multiple input boxes, which the user can input into and then that input is binded into a div. What I would like to do is have a character count that applies to all the boxes, so its one limit on all boxes and as the user types into them boxes the overall counter is affected. So far I can do this:

```
<p>xxxxxxxx?</p>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="what[$index]" id="input" maxlength="200"></textarea>
 <span>{{200 - what[$index].length}} left</span>
```

So this will give me a limit on that box, but how Can i get it so I have a overall counter? I have about 8 more text boxes and they are binded into a div as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="w in what">
    <p style="font-size:22px;"></p>
    <p>{{w}}</p>
</div>
```

app.js

```
$scope.what=[];
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

**Two Way Data-Binding**

First you need to set up 2 way data-binding so that when a user makes a change to the model it has an effect on the controller. you will use `$scope` for this since scope represents your model in Angular. then to build a running total I have 2 options for you.

**Quick and Dirty**

A quick and dirty way to count up a total across different controllers and other parts of your angular app would be to use `$rootScope.YourCountVar`. Root scope is a global variable and has its own host of problems because of this.

declare a counter near the top of your application (after `angular.module`) in app.js like this

```
.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.counter= 0;
})
```

Now in your controllers that you would like to count you need to set the value of `$rootScope` like

```
$rootScope.counter += $scope.YourInputData.length;
```

Repeat that for each of your inputs.

**Best Practice**

Create a Service that you can instantiate everywhere you need to add onto the running total. This way you only have the service where you need it. Doing things this way is much safer and cleaner and I would recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Joe, do you have a example fiddle how this would work?

Comment: Let me see if i can dig out a function or 2 to do the counting and scope binding. I'll add the code my answer.

Comment: updated the 1st one but I'll see about getting a service for you too.
hope the `$rootScope` works.

Comment: Hi Joe, it doesn't like the $rootScope... I get errors I am using angular 1.4.3?

Comment: I see, pretty sure rootScope viable across the bored but I could be wrong. do you have a github account? having a look at your code in full could give me a better Idea. #bordAtWork #dontTellTheBoss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87804/discussion-between-sole-and-joe-lloyd).